# What sort of formatting can python detect

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel, dataframe

I'm working on a project that reads in data from a excel sheet and will eventually sort through it and paste it in multiple different workbooks. Currently, the people reviewing the data file getting read into the df have to make some manual updates to that data, and when they do that they typically highlight the cell and change the font to track what's been changed. Since pandas can't detect the highlights or fonts (from what I've read), I asked if they could instead add a column at the end to track what manual changes have been made. They said they could, but asked if there was any type of formatting they could use, for instance bold/italic font, underline, etc. that they could use instead of adding a column, so I thought I would ask to see if pandas can detect anything like that in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be surprised if Pandas can, because it's interested in data, rather than the look of data. In the [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#) doc, there doesn't appear to be any support for it to detect Excel formatting.

However, I believe in Excel you can write a formula based on another cell's format, so you might be able to generate the column you need in Excel and then use that column in Panadas. I found [a post](https://www.mrexcel.com/archive/formulas/can-tou-write-a-formula-based-on-a-cells-format/) with an example;

> Well, the answer is yes, but I believe you will need a user defined function. Here is an example:
>
> Public Function GetColorIndex(cl As Range) As Integer
> GetColorIndex = cl.Interior.ColorIndex
> End Function
>
> Ok, now in your workbook you can use this formula. So say Cell A1 has a light yellow background. In cell B1, if you type the following:
>
> =GETCOLORINDEX(A1)
>
> It should return 36. So you could base your formula on the number this returns, or just use it in your formula something like this:
>
> IF(GETCOLORINDEX(A1) > 30, A1+A2, "")
>
> Hope this makes sense & helps,
>
> Russell

Comment: Good luck! I'm interested in how this goes for you. :)